# Automating tasks in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, macos, scripting, automation, development-environment

I'm curious if Xcode 4 is scriptable in some way. I'm facing code that has literals sprinkled throughout that I would like to extract. That sounds like a perfect task for a script. Any suggestions?

Comment: Xcode 3 was; you should [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com/).

Answer (score 1):

AppleScript is built into OSX and works with XCode. I think is what you are after.